# android best way to set an alarm in android

Tags: android

i have a general question to set an alarm in android.
at the moment, the user can chose a date and time with a date picker (which is a date in the future).

then i will set the the delay time for the alarm.
I convert the chosen date & time in milliseconds and subtract System.currentTimeMillis() = this difference I set for the delay of my alarm.

my question is, if this the best way to calculate the delay or is there a better solution?

this calculation i use for update an alarm, too

Comment: That's the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Android [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class. You can use it to set alarms at specific times, without calculating the delay.

```
final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) App.instance.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c.set(2015, 12, 20, 10, 30);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
```

where operation is a `PendingIntent` of the action you want to do when the alarm triggers.

Comment: Yes. In the docs you can see what methods are from what SDK version. The plain 'set' method is from SDK 1.

Comment: perfect ! this works good. but one question: c.set(2015, 12, 20, 10, 36);
how can i set minutes,seconds, and milliseconds,too?

i though: c.set(2015, 12, 20, 10, 36, 0, 0 ,0);
but this doesn't work

Comment: Look at the Calendar class for how to set each field: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html. You set the fields with c.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds); c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, millisecond);

Comment: No problem. If it works, then you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution for you here:

1. You should convert normal datetime to timestemp formart
2. You can calculate by subtract future timestemp (which is set by alarm time) with current timestemp of phone to get return value then convert it to hour, munite and day number.

   - If after calculate get result is  zezo then you notify alarm to user.
   - else nothing to do